# Python pandas how to add an accumulation counter to a neighboring column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with something like this column

| Comulative |
| --- |
| -1 |
| -3 |
| -4 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 5 |
| -1 |
| -4 |
| -8 |
| 1 |
| 3 |
| 5 |
| 10 |

I would like to add an internal column counting the number of sign shifts

To get something like this

| Comulative | Score |
| --- | --- |
| -1 | 1 |
| -3 | 2 |
| -4 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| -1 | 1 |
| -4 | 2 |
| -8 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 10 | 4 |

In my original csv file, the Comulative column usually does not change the sign from about 100 to 500 lines here , for clarity , it changes so often !

Can you tell me how to do it better ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the sign with [`numpy.sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html), then use a custom `groupby` with [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
# get sign
s = np.sign(df['Comulative'])
# group by consecutive signs
group = s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()
# enumerate
df['Score'] = s.groupby(group).cumcount().add(1)
```

*NB. if you want to consider 0 as part of the positive numbers, use `s  = df['Comulative'].gt(0)`.*

output:

```
    Comulative  Score
0           -1      1
1           -3      2
2           -4      3
3            1      1
4            2      2
5            5      3
6           -1      1
7           -4      2
8           -8      3
9            1      1
10           3      2
11           5      3
12          10      4
```

Answer (score 0):

mozway's usage of `np.sign` is far prettier, but for a more drawn out answer - you could do something like this.

```
# Marks true every time the previous value is positive, 
# and the current is negative or visa versa.
groups = (df.Comulative.lt(0) & df.Comulative.shift().gt(0) 
         | df.Comulative.gt(0) & df.Comulative.shift().lt(0)).cumsum()

df['Score'] = df.groupby(groups).cumcount().add(1)
```

Output:

```
    Comulative  Score
0           -1      1
1           -3      2
2           -4      3
3            1      1
4            2      2
5            5      3
6           -1      1
7           -4      2
8           -8      3
9            1      1
10           3      2
11           5      3
12          10      4
```